# Regular expression for string

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have string like this.

**,mon,,tue,wed,,,thu,**

I want out out put like this.

**mon,tue,wed,thu**

Is there any way to do this and store it in a string.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code sample for your problem. If you want you can remove comma from last using `removeEnd(',')`

```
string test =',mon,,tue,wed,,,thu,';
List<string> testList = test.split(',');
string newString = '';
for(String str : testList)
    if(str.getChars().size() >0)
        newString =newString+str+',';
system.debug('newString+'+newString);
```

In the new string you will get

> mon,tue,wed,thu,

you can remove last comma from **removeEnd** method(If you don't want it).

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match the commas at the end of your string and you can use it to replace them with empty string `""`

- http://regexr.com/3c07g `("^,|,$")`

This regex will look for 2 or more commas somewhere in your string except at the beginning and the end. You can use this regex to replace multiple commas with a single one `","`

- http://regexr.com/3c07d `("[,],+")`

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer is valid, I think it is much cleaner to use `String.isNotBlank` and `String.join`:

```
public static String cleanCommaJoin(String input)
{
    List<String> notBlankEntries = new List<String>();
    for (String entry : input.split(','))
        if (String.isNotBlank(entry)) notBlankEntries.add(entry.trim());
    return String.join(notBlankEntries, ',');
}
```

`String.join` is a simple solution to the common trailing delimiter anti-pattern. Because of using `String.isNotBlank`, it also still works if you had, for instance:

```
String input =' , mon, , tue, wed, , , thu, ';
String output = cleanCommaJoin(input))
system.assertEquals('mon,tue,wed,thu', output);
```

Comment: 1+ for awesome answer. Thank you so much Adrian.